# Can the same Android getIntent() receive from two different classes?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**Problem:**
When I try to "reuse" so-to-speak a `getIntent()` with extra values by passing data to it from a second activity, the extra values return null. So I want to pass NoteAdapter Intent Extras to the ViewNote class and I also want to pass EditNote Intent Extras to the ViewNote class using the same string keys.

Something like this: User chooses note  > User Views Note > User Edits Note > User Views Note corrected.

**What works:**
Based upon a user selection of a `RecyclerView` list of notes, the chosen note through a `NoteAdapter` has extra details passed to an `Intent` to a `ViewNote` class which in turn has a `Intent n = getIntent()` which these extras are received. Note details are loaded into the `ViewNote` activity. If the user decides this note needs corrected or updated, then the `ViewNote` class has an `Intent` that passes extras to the `EditNote` class. This all works great!

**What doesn't work and What I'm trying to do:**
I'm not sure whether this is allowed or can be done but I'm trying to pass **extras** back to the `ViewNote` class from the `EditNote` class using the same `Intent n = getIntent()` in the `ViewNote` class used earlier when a note was passed to it.

The ViewNote class `getIntent()`:

```
Intent n = getIntent();
nNoteID = n.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
String nType = n.getStringExtra("Type");
String nSummary = n.getStringExtra("Summary");
String nSource = n.getStringExtra("Source");
String nAuthors = n.getStringExtra("Authors");
```

The EditNote `Intent` to pass extras back to the ViewNote

```
Intent u = new Intent(EditNote.this, ViewNote.class);
u.putExtra("ID", vNoteID);
u.putExtra("Type", ty);
u.putExtra("Summary", su);
u.putExtra("Source", so);
u.putExtra("Authors",au);
EditNote.this.startActivity(u);
```

**What I have tried:**
I've read a few posts here on stackoverflow that appeared to be similar and tried changing the context (thinking maybe that was wrong), and tried using `Bundle` but neither of those made any difference. I thought maybe the `String` array values weren't passing so I just passed `String` variables because the "ID" number as a `String` seems to pass fine but the other values still return `null`. I've read some of the Android Developer explanations about Intents and maybe I just don't understand Intents fully or maybe this just can't be done or is not how it should be done.

I'm working in the following:

- Intellij Idea 2021.1.1
- Java Android v.28 Min v.29 Max
- Gradle 4.1.2

Comment: When `ViewNote` launches `EditNote` are you using `startActivityForResult()`? Does `ViewNote` call `finish()` after launching `EditNote`?

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks for responding David. No, `ViewNote` does not call `finish()` - I was not aware of that and can't recall coming across it, and it just calls `startActivity`, not `startActivityForResult`. So I have a couple things to learn and try and appreciate that. If  you have more thoughts let me know but I will try these and respond.

Comment: OK, then when `EditNote` calls `startActivity()` it should launch a NEW instance of `ViewNote` with the extras in the `Intent`. So you should then have 2 instances of `ViewNote` in the task stack.

Comment: Are you using any special `launchMode`s in the manifest?

Comment: @David Wasser: Trying to be brief -- No, I didn't add `launchMode s` in the manifest. I read and reviewed examples and tried `ViewNote` using `startActivityForResult(intent,2)` > `EditNote` with a new Intent having extras calling `setResult(2,intent)` and `finish()` back to `ViewNote`  but it still returns `null` on extras. I created the Overridden `onActivityResult(2,2,Intent)`, but the `setResult` wasn't returning to `onActivityResult`, instead, `setResult` returns to the `getIntent()`called from the `NoteAdapter` intent sent to `ViewNote` before the `EditNote Intent` is later launched.

Comment: The call to `getIntent()` always returns the `Intent` that started the `Activity`, so you won't find your "extras" in the `Intent` returned from `getIntent()` in `onActivityResult()`. You would find them in the `Intent` passed to `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Using `startActivityForResult()` is the right approach here. You should edit your question and post the code that you used in `onActivityResult()` and also the code you used to set the result in `EditNote` and we can look at that. Don't post code in comments please, it is difficult to read.

Comment: @DavidWasser -- Okay, I found my issue. I had an `Intent` that followed in the `EditNote` activity I was unaware of and it was overriding my data. So this is why things weren't working properly and coming back over blank. However, your suggestions from the start was how things should have been done, so I learned how to do this properly. Thanks for your patience and time with me. It probably was more than what most would have had the patience to give. In the future, I will avoid posting code in the comments. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you could solve your problem. To help others maybe you can create an answer that describes how you solved your problem and accept your answer. This will remove this question from the list of open questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was exactly what David Wasser posted in the initial comments above. I needed to use the `startActivityForResult` and follow the guidelines on how to do so. I did review the Android Development links and other examples online, but this video helped:

[Android startActivityForResult Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV9HfoctYdE)

These are the code segments in sequence:

ViewNote

```
menuIntent = new Intent(this, EditNote.class);
menuIntent.putExtra("NoteID", nNoteID);
menuIntent.putExtra("NoteDetails", new ArrayList<>(noteDetails));
if(noteFiles.size() > 0)
    menuIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("NoteFiles", new ArrayList<>(noteFiles));
startActivityForResult(menuIntent, REQUEST_CODE);  // REQUEST_CODE = 1
```

EditNote

```
Intent u = new Intent();
        u.putExtra("ID", vNoteID);
        u.putExtra("Type", ty);
        u.putExtra("Summary", su);
        u.putExtra("Source", so);
        u.putExtra("Authors",au);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,u);
        finish();
```

Back to ViewNote `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            nNoteID = data.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
            nType = data.getStringExtra("Type");
            nSummary = data.getStringExtra("Summary");
            nSource = data.getStringExtra("Source");
            nAuthors = data.getStringExtra("Authors");
        }
    }
}
```